# Data Binding List within a List

Tags: c#, wpf, xamarin, data-binding

i want to bind a `items` of a `list` within a `list`.

My three Models:

```
public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Module> Modules { get; set; }
}

public class Module
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Discipline> Disciplines { get; set; }
}

public class Discipline
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
 }
```

I have a page with a list of courses and pass data to another page with that course to view some details, on that detail page i set the `BindingContext` to `BindingContext = _course.Module` in `_course` i get the clicked course data.

My inquire is that now i want to display a list of Disciplines grouped by Module

I've try something like:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding .}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding Disciplines}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

or:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Disciplines}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <TextCell Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

but my listview always show empty could you guys lend me a hand?

Comment: what is the binding context of the 2nd page?

Comment: You'll need to change the Source of your binding to point to something other than the default DataContext. Look into using an `ElementName` or `RelativeSource` binding. Either should work, although which you use depends in your UI structure and preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'll post my workaround for if someone is having troubles with this but if anyone knows a better solution can post it

i've made a separate class

```
public class GroupedDisciplines : ObservableCollection<Disciplines>
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public static ObservableCollection<GroupedDisciplines> CreateGroup (ObservableCollection<Module> module)
    {
        var group = new GroupedDisciplines();
        var colection = new ObservableCollection<GroupedDisciplines>();
        foreach (Module m in module)
        {
            group = new GroupedDisciplines() { Title = m.Title };
            foreach (Discipline d in module.SelectMany(x => x.Disciplines))
            {
                group.Add(d);
            }
            colection.Add(group);
        }

        return colection;
    }
}
```

and on the view i set the BindingContext (or x:Name.ItemsSource) to

```
listView.ItemsSource = GroupedDisciplines.CriarGrupo(_modules);
```

Answer (score 0):

To show the list of Disciplines as a List of text, you can use a ListView as the data template in the first List view, and Bind the Disciplines to that template List View.
You can try :

```html
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Disciplines}">
             <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding Title}" />
              </DataTemplate>
             </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>  
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: When i do that i always get a parsing error. What i manage to do so far is convert my list of Modules to a list of Disciplines and set that as ItemSource but now i cannot group by Modules Title

Comment: Correction: cast exception on ItemsSource="{Binding}".